# My screen says /dev/sda1: clean.......blocks after login background picture change trying

Tags: boot

I tried to change my login background by changing the default one to the one below:

```
lockDialogGroup {
    background: #2c001e url(file:///usr/share/backgrounds/drawing.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit to include an actual question?

Comment: I mean i tried to customize my login background in the terminal then trying to restart inorder to see the changed, nothing really happened my screen turned  black.and popped the message " /dev/sda: clean ,205073/15630336 files, 4134430/62514432 blocks

Comment: [Edit] your question for clarity. Don't clarify in comments. Clearly state what your actual question is.

Comment: That is a good message to see when booting up.  If something else is happening(not booting) let us know in your question.

Comment: Boot to Recovery Mode, Root Access, and use `sudo pico /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css` and change the code back, then reboot.

Comment: How do I save the changes I have made? Do I exit with Ctrl X?

Comment: Wow! This worked for me. Thanks big time @heynnema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

From the GRUB menu, boot to Recovery Mode, Root Access, and use `sudo pico /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css` and change the code back, then reboot.